# Connecting Springboot application to Azure databricks

Tags: spring-boot, maven, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm trying to connect SpringBoot Application to Azure Databricks.
Below is something I have tried....

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:spark://adb-**********.*.azuredatabricks.net:**/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/******/******-*****-abcd341
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = Generated Token
```

pom.xml

Below are some dependencies I'm using...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-avro_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting below error..

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Suggest me if I'm missing any maven dependency.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1):

To connect from the Spring Boot you need to use JDBC driver, not Spark jars (remove them - you don't need them).  You can get JDBC driver as described in [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/integrations/bi/jdbc-odbc-bi.html), or very recently - directly via Maven using following coordinates:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
      <artifactId>databricks-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.25-1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then use standard JDBC APIs exposed by Spring.  I have [a simple example](https://github.com/alexott/databricks-playground/tree/main/spring-jdbc-dbsql) that uses `JdbcTemplate` to access data in Databricks - you just need to construct JDBC URL correctly:

```java
String host = "";
String httpPath = "";
String token = "";

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:databricks://" + host + 
       ":443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=" +
       httpPath + ";AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=" + token;
```

and then just access data:

```java
// define data source
SimpleDriverDataSource ds = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
ds.setDriver(new Driver());
ds.setUrl(jdbcUrl);
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(ds);

// query data
List<Map<String, Object>> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
for (Map<String, Object> row: data) {
....
}
```

P.S. You may omit `username` or at least set it to the `token` value...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "spring.datasource.driverClassName" , and let me know if that helps you to proceed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).